# Notation for composing / stitching-together geometry from a smaller geometry according to a symmetry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tiling

This will be a poorly phrased question so I apologise in advance since I am not quite sure what I am looking for. Happy to answer clarifying questions in the comments.

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

Now consider the figure on the right: the hatched section is a equilateral triangle. I am able to compose (stitch/construct) six of these triangles, by tiling them around the centroid, to create the hexagon on the left. I do this simply by repeating / creating copies of the triangle six times.

What I would like to know is, what notation can one, does one, use for this operation? I have looked here ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#:%7E:text=10%20External%20links-,Notation%20of%20Euclidean%20tilings,%3B%2036%3B%2034.)) but I find Cundy & Rollet's notation and the GomJau-Hogg notation inadequate for my purposes.

Essentially the nomenclature I am looking for takes a smaller geometry (triangle), applies an operation (tiling around the centroid), so that it produces a regular polygon (hexagon).

**EDIT**

Another example.

[image]

The nomenclature I am looking for takes a smaller geometry (square), applies an operation (tiling around the centroid), so that it produces a regular polygon (larger square).

Comment: Too general. Perhaps we can help if you [edit] the question to provide more examples. If your construction is as precise as your last paragraph, consider just inventing your own notation to use in your work.

Comment: Ah sure, let me add some more examples. The last paragraph is what I want to do in general.

Comment: there is a fair amount written about tiling the plane or the hyperbolic plane, not all in mathematics journals.   Among other people, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doris_Schattschneider   ........  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daina_Taimi%C5%86a

Comment: @WillJagy ah okay thanks! To me what I am asking seems very simple but perhaps not. Thanks for the link, will dig into that to see if I can find any clues.